# Opening InputStreamReader in the middle of UTF-8 stream

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I am using a seekable InputStream which returns the stream to me at a specific position. The underlying data in the stream is encoded with UTF-8. I want to open this stream using inputStreamReader and read one character at a time.

Here is my code snippet

```
inputStream.seek(position-1);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

The problem is that if position-1 could be pointing to the middle of a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence. How can I detect that make sure it starts from a new UTF-8 encoded sequence? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what is `position` *meant* to be? Where do you get the value from? It seems odd to have a value you trust, but not know that it's at the start of a character. (There are ways to do what you want, admittedly...)

Comment: @Jon : The underlying data stream contains serialized complex objects. Variable position is used to split this buffer and process in smaller chunks. But the split may not be exactly at an object boundary. I get the value from another process through RPC. I do not have control on how position is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can reposition the stream whenever you want, you can simply read bytes while the top two bits are "10". So something like:

```
// InputStream doesn't actually have a seek method, but I'll assume you're using
// a subclass which does...
inputStream.seek(position);
while (true) {
    int nextByte = inputStream.read();
    if (nextByte == -1 || (nextByte & 0xc0) != 0xc0) {
       break;
    }
    position++;
}
// Undo the last read, effectively
inputStream.seek(position);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```